# Can't write to /dev/console through node not in /dev

Tags: linux, files, permissions, devices

Can anyone explain this one:

Embedded Arm system, Linux 3.18.44. No SELinux or anything:

```
# ls -l /dev/console
crw-------    1 root     root        5,   1 Jan  6 02:40 /dev/console
# ls -l /tmp/console
crw-------    1 root     root        5,   1 Jan  6 02:39 /tmp/console
# echo foo > /dev/console
foo
# echo foo > /tmp/console
-sh: can't create /tmp/console: Permission denied
# ls -ld /tmp
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root            80 Jan  6 02:39 /tmp
# ls -ld /dev
drwxr-xr-x   11 root     root          5480 Jan  6 02:32 /dev
```

Some detail from `strace`:

```
# strace sh -c 'echo foo > /tmp/console' 2>&1 | grep console
execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "echo foo > /tmp/console"], [/* 12 vars */]) = 0
open("/tmp/console", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = -1 EACCES (Pe)
```

Versus:

```
# strace sh -c 'echo foo > /dev/console' 2>&1 | grep console
execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "echo foo > /dev/console"], [/* 12 vars */]) = 0
open("/dev/console", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 3
foo
```

It's the same device: major 5, minor 1. Why would the device care about the path name of the filesystem node that refers to it? If that's what the issue is, which is what it looks like:

```
# mknod -m 600 /tmp/cons c 5 1
# echo foo > /dev/cons
foo
# mknod -m 600 /tmp/cons c 5 1
# echo foo > /tmp/cons
-sh: can't create /tmp/cons: Permission denied
```

Some sort of "security theatre"?  It works under Linux 3.14 on very similar hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/tmp` is mounted **nodev** and /dev isn't ...?

Comment: Yes; it is `nodev`. That's that option for preventing device nodes with lax permissions from sneaking in via media mounts. What a surprise to see it on `/tmp`.